# Simplepie not returning a specific feed

Tags: simplepie

I have SimplePie running on my website.  It works for all RSS feeds I and the sites users have tried, except : http://investors.engilitycorp.com/corporate.rss?c=251345&Rule=Cat=news~subcat=ALL

The return is empty.

I don't see anything different than all the other feeds.

I was hoping someone might have a suggestion on were to look for a reason/fix.

Thanks

Comment: Does it work when you use ONLY that feed? Also, I'm thinking this `~subcat=ALL` might be a problem. Query params are separated by the `&` symbol, not `~`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It's wasn't simplepie,  it was the calling code.  the combination   rule=cat=new   it didn't like and the following ~subcat.    that code got fixed and all works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a malformed URL. `&Rule=Cat=news~subcat=ALL` should probably be `&Rule=&Cat=news&subcat=ALL`